# Notify controller of data change

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers, A & B, who share data using a the following service:

```
angular.module('data-sharer',[])

.factory('datasharer', function () {
  var sharedData = null;

  var setSharedData = function (data) {
    sharedData = data;
  };

  var getSharedData = function () {
    return sharedData;
  };

  return {
    setSharedData:setSharedData,
    getSharedData:getSharedData
  };
});
```

If controller A updates the data within the service, how would I notify controller B that the data within the service has changed?

My preference is to not use $rootScope & $broadcasts - it seems a bit heavy handed to tell all controllers that the data has changed.

Is there some approach with callback functions which could be used?

Comment: You could just expose the `sharedData` variable, so both your controllers point to the same instances: `return { sharedData: sharedData }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pub-sub service mechanism.

PUB-SUB: In this mechanism in case of angular, 2nd ctrl will subscribe for a method using some common service. And 1st ctrl will publish some data, as 1st ctrl publish any data then the 2nd ctrl subscribed method/function will called itself.

Please see demo here [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/Lvc0u55v/2185/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('datasharer', function () {
 var sharedData = null;
 var registeredFunc = null;

 var setSharedData = function (data) {
  registeredFunc(data)
 };

 var registerForSharedData = function (functionCb) {
  registeredFunc = functionCb;
 }

 return {
   setSharedData:setSharedData,
   getSharedData:getSharedData,
   registerForSharedData:registerForSharedData
 };
});

function MyCtrl($scope, datasharer) {
    $scope.sharedData = datasharer.getSharedData();
    $scope.send = function() {
     datasharer.setSharedData($scope.name);    
   }
}

function My2Ctrl($scope, datasharer) {
  function getSendData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.sharedData = data;
  }

 datasharer.registerForSharedData(getSendData); 
}
```

Comment: First, your code creates memory leak.Second,  I doubpt such services is a good idea in general -- it looks like global variables. I really wish too see how you will use too pairs of such controllers on one page -- create 2 services?

Comment: Hi Petr, where is the memory leak in the example?

Answer (score 0):

use broadcast for this purpose
send broadcast from controller A

$rootScope.$broadcast('scanner-started', { any: {} });

recieve broadcast from controller B
$scope.$on('scanner-started', function(event, args) {

```
var anyThing = args.any;
// do what you want to do
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few months ago, i found this to be useful:

https://github.com/pviraj/Angular-Service-To-Share-Data-Beween-Controllers

Essentially its a service with getters and setters which are called on controller load.

Comment: That works fine when your controllers are on different pages, or your second controller is instantiated after the first. The problem I have is that both of my controllers are on the same page. When I click on an item in view A, view B needs to be updated with the selected item.

Comment: @DonalM - ah i see. Ok, then Broadcast will work perfectly. If you would like an example, please let me know. They are very simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, a broadcast is meant for this. Also, as mentioned, using a service as the central source for your data will work as well.

Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gzgkz3cr/

```
function Service() {
  var service = {
    data: {
      name: 'Rob'
    }
  };

  return service;
}

function ControllerA(Service, $rootScope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.data = angular.copy(Service.data);
  vm.updateData = updateData;

  function updateData() {
    Service.data.name = vm.data.name;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('data_updated', vm.data);
  }
}

function ControllerB(Service, $scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.data = Service.data;

  $scope.$on('data_updated', function(e, data) {
    alert('new data: ' + data.name);
  });
}
```